Create a shared css asset for all the blocks theme app extension
I am developing custom blocks through a theme app extension, however, I am planning to use tailwind to add the styles to these components, so I need to have a common css asset to use these styles on any block, if I add this resource in every block the same file it will be loaded multiple times.
{{ 'tailwind-styles.css' | asset_url | stylesheet_tag }} // -> I have to add this line to every block in my extension folder

<div>
  Custom Block
</div>

{% schema %}

{% endschema %}

I would like to know if there is a way to load this style file only once and that every block in my extension can access to these styles.
Thanks a lot

{% schema %}
  {
    "name": "Block name",
    "target": "section",
    "stylesheet": "custom.css",
    "javascript": "custom.js"
  }
{% endschema %}

That's how you have to add the CSS or JS to your block.
Shopify theme extension example
